# Link to list which contains frequnecy ranks of all English language words

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, word-frequency

Does any body knows link to the list which contains frequency rank of all english language words.
Some sixth months back, I found one list on 'wiki' which contains this list, but unfortunately I did not bookmark it and now I am unable to find the same link or any better link.
If anybody has this link or something better, please post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some links would include:

- [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary%3aFrequency_lists)
- [Word frequency info](http://www.wordfrequency.info/)
- [Google Answers discussion of English word frequencies pointing to British National Corpus](http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview?id=470042)
- [A different pointer to British National Corpus and how to use it](http://ucrel.lancs.ac.uk/bncfreq/)